# Downgrading kubuntu backports to official repositories: could not find package list for PPA

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, kubuntu, ppa

I have added the [Kubuntu backports PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports). This somehow messed up my system.

Now I want to remove the PPA and downgrade all the packages to the version provided in the official repositories.

I followed [this AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50821/downgrade-ppa-packages-to-versions-available-at-a-previous-point-in-time) and run `ppa-purge`. But it returned me the following error:

```
$ sudo ppa-purge http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu/ 
Updating packages lists
PPA to be removed: http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu ppa
Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu ppa
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

You have to re-add the PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get update
```

and the run `ppa-purge` using the **PPA name, not the URL**:

`sudo ppa-purge ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports`